# What does the public Gui() mean in my code? what is it?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, constructor, jcheckbox

So I was making a Gui and I did the usual stuff, and I always do `public Gui()` {and have code in it}. what does it mean? Is it a constructor? What is it?

```
package tacos;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Gui extends JFrame{ 
private JTextField tf;
private JCheckBox boldbox;
private JCheckBox italicbox;

public Gui(){ //what does this public Gui thing mean?
    super("the title");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    tf = new JTextField("this is a sentence", 20);
    tf.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14));
    add(tf);

    boldbox = new JCheckBox("bold");
    italicbox = new JCheckBox("italic");
    add(boldbox);
    add(italicbox);


    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    boldbox.addItemListener(handler);
    italicbox.addItemListener(handler);



    }



}
```

Comment: It is a constructor.

Comment: That is the constructor for your `GUI` class, every time you instantiate a new `GUI` object through `GUI gui = new GUI();`, that code is called.

Answer (score 1):

`Gui` in your code is a constructor. It can be identified by the fact that it has the same name as the class and no return value.